# What password/key does AWS use for AES-256 encryption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aes

I noticed that if I want to encrypt an object using **AES-256** encryption, I don't have to select a key/password. Obviously, **AWS** manages the key/password internally. How does it do it? What if the password **AWS** uses is stolen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You are correct](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html).  Amazon uses a unique key to encrypt each object, and in turn to "protect" this key, it encrypts the key itself:

> As an additional safeguard, it encrypts the key itself with a master
>   key that it regularly rotates

Obviously the specifics of how this all works is not going to be provided to you because s3 is SaaS.  You are interacting with it using REST.  If your concern is that you do not trust amazon not to be hacked, or that amazon employees might access your data, then you should encrypt it yourself before uploading to s3.